# Can a view appear at the location where the user touches the screen, and disappear?

Tags: android, layout, view, popup, touch

I'm new to android development. Is it possible for a view (with a particular layout) to "appear" at the location where the user "touches"? If so, how?
Like the idea of right-clicking on your computer - a menu pops down wherever you right-click.
and when you navigate away, it disappears.

I hope what I said made sense :P
Thanks!

Comment: As techiServices pointed out, there are ways to do this, but the platform generally provides better means for what you're trying to accomplish, like the context and options menus.  What user feature are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  You need to capture the touch event, say overriding onTouchEvent on the Activity or ViewGroup.  Then you can either inflate and add or make visible the view at the touch point.  There are a number of different ways of achieving this depending on what Layout you are using i.e. AbsoluteLayout (iirc that is deprecated though) you can set x, y positions or add view in code or xml but make it invisible and move it to the touch point through mainpulation of it's Matrix (translate) and then make it Visible.  You can even make the View appear and then slide it to the touch point using the Matrix (translate) via an Animation.

You can even do all this on plain bitmaps etc via onDraw.